# Has any one setup done local travis ci process

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, travis-ci, travis-ci-api

I have created a local travis-build container, can any one help me to do the following

1. Once the developer check-in code travis build should trigger.
2. if the build is success code should get check-in.
3. if the build fails code shouldn't check-in.

Suggest me the which repository i have to use to do this and can i do it with jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to use Travis CI on your local/on-prem is to purchase Travis CI Enterprise edition;

- https://landing.travis-ci.com/enterprise/
- https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/enterprise/